# convert from one column pandas dataframe to 3 columns based on index

Tags: pandas, reshape

I have:

```
    col1
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5
5   6
...
```

I want, every 3 rows of the original dataframe to become a single row in the new dataframe:

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   1       2       3
1   4       5       6
...
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values of the dataframe are an array that can be reshaped using numpy's reshape method. Then, create a new dataframe using the reshaped values. Assuming your existing dataframe is df-

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(2, 3), columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```

This will create the new dataframe of two rows and 3 columns.

```
   col1   col2  col3
0   0      1      2
1   3      4      5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set_index` and `unstack` to get the right shape, and `add_preffix` to change the column name:

```
print (df.set_index([df.index//3, df.index%3+1])['col1'].unstack().add_prefix('col'))
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     2     3
1     4     5     6
```

in case the original index is not consecutive values but you still want to reshape every 3 rows, replace `df.index` by `np.arange(len(df))` for both in the `set_index`

Answer (score 0):

you can covert the col in numpy array and then reshape.

```
In [27]: np.array(df['col1']).reshape( len(df) // 3 , 3 )
Out[27]:
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])

In [..] :reshaped_cols = np.array(df['col1']).reshape( len(df) // 3 , 3 )


pd.DataFrame( data = reshaped_cols , columns = ['col1' , 'col2' , 'col3' ] )


Out[30]:
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     2     3
1     4     5     6
```